# Expected number of times to choose a specific value after $k$ attempts.

Tags: probability

There are $m$ balls in an urn, one of which is red. If $m$ is large, the probability of picking the red ball at least once after $k$ attempts (replacing the ball each time) is approximately 
$$ 1 - e^{-\frac{k}{m}}$$
This is because the probability of not picking the red ball $k$ times in a row is
$$ \bigg(1- \frac{1}{m} \bigg)^k \approx e^{-\frac{k}{m}}$$
My question is : what is the expected number of times that I picked the red ball (having chosen and replaced $k$ times)? I have in mind the situation where $k$ is less than $m$. Certainly it is less then one.
I understand and can prove that the expected number of tries before i get the red ball is $m$, but I'm not sure how to think about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let random variable $X_i$ be $1$ if we pick  red on the $i$-th try, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number $Y$ of times we pick the red is given by $Y=X_1+\cdots+X_k$. By the linearity of expectation, the expectation of $Y$ is $kE(X_1)$, which is $\frac{k}{m}$.

**Another way:** The number of times  we pick red has binomial distribution, parameters $n=k$ and $p=\frac{1}{m}$. By a standard result, the expected number of successes is $np$.